# Does anyone know if it's possible to solve $x^x=x+1$ in terms of $x$?

Tags: tetration

So I have tried solving for $x$ algebraicly using the productlog function but all I was able to do is:
$$x\log(x) = W(x\log(x)(x+1))$$

Maybe I could use the square-super root formula $e^{W(\log(x))}$, but I got stuck again at:
$$W(\log(x+1))=x$$

I feel like I'm only getting deeper into a rabbit hole rather than getting out here, so is it even possible to represent $x$ (which roughly equals 1.776775) in terms of elementary functions and the Lambert $W$-function?

Comment: Proving that such equations don't have a elementary solution is often an open question or very very difficult. So I think the best answer you'll get in this site is "Probably not".

Comment: It was partially answered here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3726436/how-to-solve-xx-x-1?rq=1

Comment: Don't know whether this helps, but maybe it is inspirating: there has been an engaged article about the solutions/inverse involving $x^x$. This was online in the nineties - as a simple ascii-text. I formatted it into a pdf-file. "Wexzal" (Fantini/Kloepfer 1995(?). https://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/WexZal.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Lambert function will not be of any use for this problem which is purely numerical.

Consider that you look for the non-trivial zero of function
$$f(x)=x^x-x-1$$
The first derivative
$$f'(x)=x^x (\log (x)+1)-1$$ cancels at $x=1$ and $f(1)=-1$. So, for an approximation, expand as a series
$$f(x)=-1+(x-1)^2+\frac{1}{2} (x-1)^3+\frac{1}{3} (x-1)^4+\frac{1}{12}
   (x-1)^5+O\left((x-1)^6\right)$$ Using series reversion
$$x=1+t-\frac{t^2}{4}-\frac{t^3}{96}+\frac{t^4}{12}+O\left(t^{5}\right)\quad \text{where}\quad t=\sqrt{1+f(x)}$$ Since you want $f(x)=0$, then the *approximation*
$$x \sim \frac{175}{96}=1.82292\cdots$$ which is not too bad. Now, you can polish the root with very few iterations of Newton method
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.822916667 \\
 1 & 1.779309489 \\
 2 & 1.776783063 \\
 3 & 1.776775040
\end{array}
\right)$$

If you really want to see something with Lambert, make the expansion around $x=3\Omega$ $(\Omega=W(1))$ since
$$f(3\Omega)=-0.231333$$ Using series and then series reversion wuld give
$$x\sim 3 \Omega+\frac{-3^{3 \Omega } \Omega ^{3 \Omega }+3 \Omega +1}{3^{3 \Omega } \Omega ^{3
   \Omega } (\log (3 \Omega )+1)-1}=1.78456$$

**Edit**

If you know about Padé approximants,
$$f(x)+1=\frac{(x-1)^2+\frac{49}{90} (x-1)^3 } {1+\frac{2 }{45}(x-1)-\frac{16}{45} (x-1)^2+\frac{43}{540}   (x-1)^3 }+O((x-1)^7)$$ Let $t=x-1$ and $f(x)=0$ to face a cubic equation
$$251 t^3+732 t^2-24 t-540=0$$ which has three real roots. Using the trigonometric method, they are
$$t_k=\frac{4}{251} \left(7 \sqrt{314} \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \left(2 \pi  k-\cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{124897}{61544 \sqrt{314}}\right)\right)\right)-61\right)\quad \quad k=0,1,2$$ The one of interest is $t_0$ which, numerically, is $0.776346$ making $x=1.776346$ while the exact solution is $1.776775$.

Comment: Claude once again exquisitely showing how to solve for that which does not like to be solved for. +1

Comment: @Graviton. Thanks for the kind words. Cheers :-)