# exact solution to $x+x^x=3$

Tags: lambert-w

I'm trying to find the exact solution to the equation $x+x^x=3$. I know the answer is approximately 1.4, but what is its formal definition? I understand it may not be from the result of a real function, since the exact solution to its brother, $x^x=3$, requires use of the Lambert W function for its formal definition ($x=e^{W(\ln 3)} $), which cannot be expressed in elementary terms. I have tried looking this equation up on Wolfram alpha but it can only approximate $x$. What would be the exact definition of this variable?

Comment: What is the source of the problem and why numerical approximation is not satisfactory? I doubt the solution can be expressed using Lambert W.

Comment: im doing this more so out of interest and less related to practical applications

Comment: AFAIK, there's no "closed-form" expression.  You'll just have to settle for the numerical solution $x \approx 1.3994607812259618$.

Comment: How did you arrive to this conclusion?

Comment: No, it is not, @K.defaoite That is the solution to $x^x=3.$ $x+x^x=3$ has a different solution.

Comment: In general, even with the $W$ function, you can't get closed formula for solutions of this kind of equation

Comment: There are ways to approximate the solution. Since $x+x^x$ is increasing on $x>1,$ we can just do a binary search, for example, starting with the interval $[0,1].$ It might be faster to apply something like Newton's method.

Comment: Even simple lagrange reversion [fails](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a%2Bsum%5B%28-1%29%5En%2Fn%21+D%5Ba%5E%28n+a%29%2C%7Ba%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C8%7D%5D%2Ca%3D0.6) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5Ex%2Bx%2Cx%3D1.12746) for inverting $x^x+x$

Comment: No exact form :(

Comment: It converges slowly, but [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) works [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5Bx%2B1%2F2+x%5Ex%2C22%5D%2Cx%3Da%2Bsum%5B%28-1%2F2%29%5En%2Fn%21+D%5B%28a%5E%28a+n%29%29%2C%7Ba%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C9%7D%5D%2Ca%3D0.5) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=exp%28ln%28a%29%2Bsum%5B%28-1%2F2%29%5En%2Fn%21+D%5B%281%2Fa+a%5E%28a+n%29%29%2C%7Ba%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C9%7D%5D%29%2Ca%3D0.75) for inverting $x+\frac12 x^x$

Comment: @Tyma: That looks interesting! I didn't know about it, thanks! I usually only use basic Fixed Point Iteration, Newton's Method...

Comment: See also : https://tetrationforum.org/showthread.php?tid=1258  where $x^x = x $ is discussed.

Answer (score 1):

Irrational numbers are usually defined as solutions of equations, for example $x^2=2$, as limits, say $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{4}{2k+1}$ or $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{1/n}$, or by introducing new notation, say $\sqrt{2},\pi$ or $e$. You stated the definition as a solution of an equation.
Since introducing new notation is not helpful in this case, I only propose the following two alternatives. Let $x^*\in(0,\infty)$ be the solution of $x+x^x=3$.

1. Limit: Consider the sequence given by $a_0=1$ and $a_{k+1}=\frac{3}{1+a_k^{a_k-1}}$ for $k\ge 0$. The sequence $(a_k)_k$ converges to the solution of the equation, i.e. $x^*=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}a_k$.
2. Using the inverse function: Let $f:[1,\infty)\rightarrow(0,\infty)$, $x\mapsto x+x^x$, and notice that $f$ is strictly increasing since $f'(x)=1+(\ln(x)+1)x^x>2$, so the solution of the equation is $x^*=f^{-1}(3)$.

These would be three common ways (equation, limit, function value) to formally define the number $x^*$. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

$$x+x^x=3$$

We see, this equation is a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($x,x^x$) and with no univariate factor. We therefore don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (elementary operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

$$x+e^{x\ln(x)}=3$$
$$e^{x\ln(x)}=3-x$$
$$1=(3-x)e^{-x\ln(x)}$$
$$(3-x)e^{-x\ln(x)}=1$$

We see, we cannot solve the equation in terms of Lambert W because of the exponent of the exponential.

$x\to 3-t$:
$$te^{(t-3)\ln(3-t)}=1$$

We see, the equation can be solved in terms of Hyper Lambert W.

$$G((t-3)\ln(3-t)e^{-t};t)=1$$
$$t=HW((t-3)\ln(3-t)e^{-t};1)$$
$$x=3-HW((t-3)\ln(3-t)e^{-t};1)$$

So we have a closed form for $x$, and the representations of Hyper Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.

[Galidakis, I. N.: On solving the p-th complex auxiliary equation $f^{(p)}(z)=z$. Complex Variables 50 (2005) (13) 977-997](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233129552_On_solving_the_p-th_complex_auxiliary_equation_fpzz)

[Galidakis, I. N.: On some applications of the generalized hyper-Lambert functions. Complex Variables and Elliptic Equations 52 (2007) (12) 1101-1119](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233200491_On_some_applications_of_the_generalized_hyper-Lambert_functions)

Comment: You used a similar method [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053472/how-to-solve-keplers-equation-m-e-varepsilon-sin-e-for-e/4733405#4733405)

Comment: Hyper Lambert W can be used i.a. for equations of the form $az+bf(z)=c$ or $(a+bz)f(z)=c$ if $f(z)$ is a tower of exponentials.

Comment: See also : https://tetrationforum.org/showthread.php?tid=1258  where $x^x = x $ is discussed.